# code vba stops coping cell in the first space

Tags: vba, excel

I have a little problem with my code , it works as i want when i was just testing it , but when i put it in the real work i faced a problem that i couldn't solve here is the issue

the code compare 2 columns to other 2 columns and stocks the result in other 3 columns the problem is that when he copies the data from the cell he stops when there is a blank between characters so it copy only the first words for example if i had  ''Air Approval always needed'' he copies only ''Air'' but not the hole chain can you please help me solving this problem and thank you in advance

```
Sub comparer()
Dim Derlig As Long, Lig As Long, Ref As String
Dim T_ab, D_ab As Object, T_cd, D_cd As Object
Dim T_fgh, Cptr As Long, Separ
Dim start As Single

    start = Timer
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Range("E2:G30000").Clear

    Set D_ab = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     Derlig = Columns("A").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    T_ab = Range("A2:B" & Derlig)
    For Lig = 1 To UBound(T_ab)
        Ref = T_ab(Lig, 1) & " " & T_ab(Lig, 2)
        If Not D_ab.exists(Ref) Then D_ab.Add Ref, ""
    Next
    T_ab = D_ab.keys

    Set D_cd = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
     Derlig = Columns("C").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    T_cd = Range("C2:D" & Derlig)
    For Lig = 1 To UBound(T_cd)
        Ref = T_cd(Lig, 1) & " " & T_cd(Lig, 2)
        If Not D_cd.exists(Ref) Then D_cd.Add Ref, ""
    Next
    T_cd = D_cd.keys


    ReDim T_fgh(3, 0) 
    For Lig = 0 To UBound(T_ab)
        If Not D_cd.exists(T_ab(Lig)) Then
            Separ = Split(T_ab(Lig))
            ReDim Preserve T_fgh(3, Cptr)
            T_fgh(0, Cptr) = Separ(0)
            T_fgh(1, Cptr) = Separ(1)
          Cptr = Cptr + 1
        End If
    Next

    For Lig = 0 To UBound(T_cd)
        If Not D_ab.exists(T_cd(Lig)) Then
            Separ = Split(T_cd(Lig))
            ReDim Preserve T_fgh(3, Cptr)
            T_fgh(0, Cptr) = Separ(0)
            T_fgh(2, Cptr) = Separ(1)
          Cptr = Cptr + 1
        End If
    Next

    Range("F2").Resize(Cptr, 3) = Application.Transpose(T_fgh)
    Derlig = Range("E2:H100000").Find(what:="*", searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    Range("F2:H" & Derlig).Borders.Weight = xlThin

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "comparaison efffectuée en " & Timer - start & " secondes"

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd start by **dim**ensioning your variables properly and giving them understandable names. At the moment your working with variants and it's extremely awkward to read.

Comment: hi thanx for responding , but i don't understand what do you mean ?

Comment: `Dim T_ab, D_ab As Object` < this creates a `Variant` and an `Object` because they aren't declared properly. Also things like `T_ab` and `D_ab` mean nothing to us which makes your code hard to read.

Comment: this is a link to my file if that would help  http://www.cjoint.com/c/FCEhZSO3Bev

Comment: T_ab and D_ab are the concatenation between the column 'a' and the column  'b' and the same for columns C and D

Answer (score 0):

for all who are interested this is the solution for the problem it was easy but i just couldn't see it in the beginning i needed only to add "¤"  in  `Separ = Split(T_cd(Lig), "¤")`to complete all the chain